# MS Graph Java SDK throwing authentication exceptions

Tags: java, authentication, oauth, microsoft-graph-api

I'm trying to use Username/Password authentication for a Microsoft Graph files request (in conjunction with an AD account created for this purpose, since we want to limit access to only specific directories within SharePoint). I wrote some code using .Net Core's Graph SDK (working a-ok) that I'm porting to Java for a different application, and I can't get it to authenticate. I pasted the Java code I'm trying to run, its .Net Core equivalent, and lastly the whole debug-level log output from a run of the Java code.

I got the Java code as close as possible, but I didn't see an equivalent of the `.WithUsernamePassword(email, password)` method (probably since the Java SDK gives the username and password directly to the constructor of `UsernamePasswordProvider`).

I'm using v0.2.0 of the Auth library and v2.2.0 of the main SDK. I raised this as [an issue](https://github.com/microsoftgraph/msgraph-sdk-java-auth/issues/55) with the msgraph-sdk-java-auth library, as it seems likely this might be a bug in the SDK, but I'm also curious for someone else to look at my Java code and let me know if I'm doing anything wrong, which is more likely.

#### Java code producing the exception

```java
    @Test
    public void authError() {
        final String userAccountEmail = //
        final String userAccountPassword = //
        final String siteID = //
        final String driveID = //
        final String clientID = //
        final String filePath = //

        final IAuthenticationProvider authProvider = new UsernamePasswordProvider(clientID, Arrays.asList(), userAccountEmail, userAccountPassword);
        final IGraphServiceClient graphClient = GraphServiceClient.builder()
            .authenticationProvider(authProvider)
            .buildClient();
        graphClient.getLogger().setLoggingLevel(LoggerLevel.DEBUG);
        graphClient
            .sites(siteID)
            .drives(driveID).root()
            .itemWithPath(filePath)
            .buildRequest()
            .get();
    }
```

#### Working C# code (.Net Core, no exception, result is as expected)

```c#
        [Fact]
        public void authError()
        {
            var userAccountEmail = //
            var userAccountPassword = //
            var siteID = //
            var driveID = //
            var tenant = //
            var clientID = //
            var filePath = //
            var securePassword = new NetworkCredential("", userAccountPassword).SecurePassword;

            var publicClientApplication = PublicClientApplicationBuilder
                .Create(clientID)
                .WithTenantId(tenant)
                .Build();

            var graphClient = new GraphServiceClient(new UsernamePasswordProvider(publicClientApplication));

            graphClient
                .Sites[siteID]
                .Drives[driveID].Root
                .ItemWithPath(filePath)
                .Request()
                .WithUsernamePassword(userAccountEmail, securePassword)
                .GetAsync().GetAwaiter().GetResult();
        }
```

#### Full Java debug-level log output

```
Sep 23, 2020 6:13:53 PM com.microsoft.graph.logger.DefaultLogger setLoggingLevel
INFO: Setting logging level to DEBUG
OAuthProblemException{error='unsupported_response_type', description='Invalid response! Response body is not application/json encoded', uri='null', state='null', scope='null', redirectUri='null', responseStatus=0, parameters={}}
    at org.apache.oltu.oauth2.common.exception.OAuthProblemException.error(OAuthProblemException.java:63)
    at org.apache.oltu.oauth2.client.response.OAuthJSONAccessTokenResponse.setBody(OAuthJSONAccessTokenResponse.java:76)
    at org.apache.oltu.oauth2.client.response.OAuthClientResponse.init(OAuthClientResponse.java:92)
    at org.apache.oltu.oauth2.client.response.OAuthAccessTokenResponse.init(OAuthAccessTokenResponse.java:65)
    at org.apache.oltu.oauth2.client.response.OAuthClientResponse.init(OAuthClientResponse.java:101)
    at org.apache.oltu.oauth2.client.response.OAuthAccessTokenResponse.init(OAuthAccessTokenResponse.java:60)
    at org.apache.oltu.oauth2.client.response.OAuthClientResponse.init(OAuthClientResponse.java:120)
    at org.apache.oltu.oauth2.client.response.OAuthClientResponseFactory.createCustomResponse(OAuthClientResponseFactory.java:82)
    at org.apache.oltu.oauth2.client.URLConnectionClient.execute(URLConnectionClient.java:111)
    at org.apache.oltu.oauth2.client.OAuthClient.accessToken(OAuthClient.java:65)
    at org.apache.oltu.oauth2.client.OAuthClient.accessToken(OAuthClient.java:55)
    at org.apache.oltu.oauth2.client.OAuthClient.accessToken(OAuthClient.java:71)
    at com.microsoft.graph.auth.publicClient.UsernamePasswordProvider.getAccessTokenNewRequest(UsernamePasswordProvider.java:98)
    at com.microsoft.graph.auth.publicClient.UsernamePasswordProvider.getAccessToken(UsernamePasswordProvider.java:71)
    at com.microsoft.graph.auth.publicClient.UsernamePasswordProvider.authenticateRequest(UsernamePasswordProvider.java:62)
    at com.microsoft.graph.http.CoreHttpProvider.sendRequestInternal(CoreHttpProvider.java:382)
    at com.microsoft.graph.http.CoreHttpProvider.send(CoreHttpProvider.java:207)
    at com.microsoft.graph.http.CoreHttpProvider.send(CoreHttpProvider.java:187)
    at com.microsoft.graph.http.BaseRequest.send(BaseRequest.java:345)
    at com.microsoft.graph.requests.extensions.DriveItemRequest.get(DriveItemRequest.java:84)
    at com.orion.FileAccess.graph.GraphConnectionTest.authError(GraphConnectionTest.java:73)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:50)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:26)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:325)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:78)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:57)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:26)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
    at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:137)
    at com.intellij.junit4.JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.java:69)
    at com.intellij.rt.junit.IdeaTestRunner$Repeater.startRunnerWithArgs(IdeaTestRunner.java:33)
    at com.intellij.rt.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:220)
    at com.intellij.rt.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:53)
Sep 23, 2020 6:13:54 PM com.microsoft.graph.logger.DefaultLogger logDebug
INFO: Starting to send request, URL https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/sites/<site ID>/drives/<drive ID>/root:/OneDriveConnector.Tests:
Sep 23, 2020 6:13:54 PM com.microsoft.graph.logger.DefaultLogger logDebug
INFO: Request Method GET
Sep 23, 2020 6:13:54 PM com.microsoft.graph.logger.DefaultLogger logDebug
INFO: Response code 401, Unauthorized
Sep 23, 2020 6:13:54 PM com.microsoft.graph.logger.DefaultLogger logDebug
INFO: Handling error response
Sep 23, 2020 6:13:54 PM com.microsoft.graph.logger.DefaultLogger logDebug
INFO: Deserializing type GraphErrorResponse
Sep 23, 2020 6:13:54 PM com.microsoft.graph.logger.DefaultLogger logError
SEVERE: CoreHttpProvider[send] - 207Graph service exception Error code: InvalidAuthenticationToken
Sep 23, 2020 6:13:54 PM com.microsoft.graph.logger.DefaultLogger logError
SEVERE: CoreHttpProvider[send] - 207Error message: CompactToken parsing failed with error code: 80049217
Sep 23, 2020 6:13:54 PM com.microsoft.graph.logger.DefaultLogger logError
SEVERE: CoreHttpProvider[send] - 207
Sep 23, 2020 6:13:54 PM com.microsoft.graph.logger.DefaultLogger logError
SEVERE: CoreHttpProvider[send] - 207GET https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/sites/<site ID>/drives/<drive ID>/root:/OneDriveConnector.Tests:
Sep 23, 2020 6:13:54 PM com.microsoft.graph.logger.DefaultLogger logError
SEVERE: CoreHttpProvider[send] - 207SdkVersion : graph-java/v2.2.0
Sep 23, 2020 6:13:54 PM com.microsoft.graph.logger.DefaultLogger logError
SEVERE: CoreHttpProvider[send] - 207Authorization : [PII_REDACTED]
Sep 23, 2020 6:13:54 PM com.microsoft.graph.logger.DefaultLogger logError
SEVERE: CoreHttpProvider[send] - 207
Sep 23, 2020 6:13:54 PM com.microsoft.graph.logger.DefaultLogger logError
SEVERE: CoreHttpProvider[send] - 207
Sep 23, 2020 6:13:54 PM com.microsoft.graph.logger.DefaultLogger logError
SEVERE: CoreHttpProvider[send] - 207401 : Unauthorized
Sep 23, 2020 6:13:54 PM com.microsoft.graph.logger.DefaultLogger logError
SEVERE: CoreHttpProvider[send] - 207Cache-Control : private
Sep 23, 2020 6:13:54 PM com.microsoft.graph.logger.DefaultLogger logError
SEVERE: CoreHttpProvider[send] - 207client-request-id : d73219c9-d26e-4972-9598-2a0ca6b6b8df
Sep 23, 2020 6:13:54 PM com.microsoft.graph.logger.DefaultLogger logError
SEVERE: CoreHttpProvider[send] - 207Content-Length : 333
Sep 23, 2020 6:13:54 PM com.microsoft.graph.logger.DefaultLogger logError
SEVERE: CoreHttpProvider[send] - 207Content-Type : application/json
Sep 23, 2020 6:13:54 PM com.microsoft.graph.logger.DefaultLogger logError
SEVERE: CoreHttpProvider[send] - 207Date : Wed, 23 Sep 2020 22:13:54 GMT
Sep 23, 2020 6:13:54 PM com.microsoft.graph.logger.DefaultLogger logError
SEVERE: CoreHttpProvider[send] - 207request-id : 61be66ec-05e4-408f-9aa5-dec61829cea6
Sep 23, 2020 6:13:54 PM com.microsoft.graph.logger.DefaultLogger logError
SEVERE: CoreHttpProvider[send] - 207Strict-Transport-Security : max-age=31536000
Sep 23, 2020 6:13:54 PM com.microsoft.graph.logger.DefaultLogger logError
SEVERE: CoreHttpProvider[send] - 207WWW-Authenticate : Bearer realm="", authorization_uri="https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/authorize", client_id="00000003-0000-0000-c000-000000000000"
Sep 23, 2020 6:13:54 PM com.microsoft.graph.logger.DefaultLogger logError
SEVERE: CoreHttpProvider[send] - 207x-ms-ags-diagnostic : {"ServerInfo":{"DataCenter":"North Central US","Slice":"SliceC","Ring":"2","ScaleUnit":"000","RoleInstance":"AGSFE_IN_10"}}
Sep 23, 2020 6:13:54 PM com.microsoft.graph.logger.DefaultLogger logError
SEVERE: CoreHttpProvider[send] - 207{
Sep 23, 2020 6:13:54 PM com.microsoft.graph.logger.DefaultLogger logError
SEVERE: CoreHttpProvider[send] - 207  "error": {
Sep 23, 2020 6:13:54 PM com.microsoft.graph.logger.DefaultLogger logError
SEVERE: CoreHttpProvider[send] - 207    "code": "InvalidAuthenticationToken",
Sep 23, 2020 6:13:54 PM com.microsoft.graph.logger.DefaultLogger logError
SEVERE: CoreHttpProvider[send] - 207    "message": "CompactToken parsing failed with error code: 80049217",
Sep 23, 2020 6:13:54 PM com.microsoft.graph.logger.DefaultLogger logError
SEVERE: CoreHttpProvider[send] - 207    "innerError": {
Sep 23, 2020 6:13:54 PM com.microsoft.graph.logger.DefaultLogger logError
SEVERE: CoreHttpProvider[send] - 207      "date": "2020-09-23T22:13:54",
Sep 23, 2020 6:13:54 PM com.microsoft.graph.logger.DefaultLogger logError
SEVERE: CoreHttpProvider[send] - 207      "request-id": "61be66ec-05e4-408f-9aa5-dec61829cea6",
Sep 23, 2020 6:13:54 PM com.microsoft.graph.logger.DefaultLogger logError
SEVERE: CoreHttpProvider[send] - 207      "client-request-id": "d73219c9-d26e-4972-9598-2a0ca6b6b8df"
Sep 23, 2020 6:13:54 PM com.microsoft.graph.logger.DefaultLogger logError
SEVERE: CoreHttpProvider[send] - 207    }
Sep 23, 2020 6:13:54 PM com.microsoft.graph.logger.DefaultLogger logError
SEVERE: CoreHttpProvider[send] - 207  }
Sep 23, 2020 6:13:54 PM com.microsoft.graph.logger.DefaultLogger logError
SEVERE: CoreHttpProvider[send] - 207}
Sep 23, 2020 6:13:54 PM com.microsoft.graph.logger.DefaultLogger logError
SEVERE: Throwable detail: com.microsoft.graph.http.GraphServiceException: Error code: InvalidAuthenticationToken
Error message: CompactToken parsing failed with error code: 80049217

GET https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/sites/<site ID>/drives/<drive ID>/root:/OneDriveConnector.Tests:
SdkVersion : graph-java/v2.2.0
Authorization : [PII_REDACTED]


401 : Unauthorized
Cache-Control : private
client-request-id : d73219c9-d26e-4972-9598-2a0ca6b6b8df
Content-Length : 333
Content-Type : application/json
Date : Wed, 23 Sep 2020 22:13:54 GMT
request-id : 61be66ec-05e4-408f-9aa5-dec61829cea6
Strict-Transport-Security : max-age=31536000
WWW-Authenticate : Bearer realm="", authorization_uri="https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/authorize", client_id="00000003-0000-0000-c000-000000000000"
x-ms-ags-diagnostic : {"ServerInfo":{"DataCenter":"North Central US","Slice":"SliceC","Ring":"2","ScaleUnit":"000","RoleInstance":"AGSFE_IN_10"}}
{
  "error": {
    "code": "InvalidAuthenticationToken",
    "message": "CompactToken parsing failed with error code: 80049217",
    "innerError": {
      "date": "2020-09-23T22:13:54",
      "request-id": "61be66ec-05e4-408f-9aa5-dec61829cea6",
      "client-request-id": "d73219c9-d26e-4972-9598-2a0ca6b6b8df"
    }
  }
}


com.microsoft.graph.http.GraphServiceException: Error code: InvalidAuthenticationToken
Error message: CompactToken parsing failed with error code: 80049217

GET https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/sites/<site ID>/drives/<drive ID>/root:/OneDriveConnector.Tests:
SdkVersion : graph-java/v2.2.0
Authorization : [PII_REDACTED]


401 : Unauthorized
Cache-Control : private
client-request-id : d73219c9-d26e-4972-9598-2a0ca6b6b8df
Content-Length : 333
Content-Type : application/json
Date : Wed, 23 Sep 2020 22:13:54 GMT
request-id : 61be66ec-05e4-408f-9aa5-dec61829cea6
Strict-Transport-Security : max-age=31536000
WWW-Authenticate : Bearer realm="", authorization_uri="https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/authorize", client_id="00000003-0000-0000-c000-000000000000"
x-ms-ags-diagnostic : {"ServerInfo":{"DataCenter":"North Central US","Slice":"SliceC","Ring":"2","ScaleUnit":"000","RoleInstance":"AGSFE_IN_10"}}
{
  "error": {
    "code": "InvalidAuthenticationToken",
    "message": "CompactToken parsing failed with error code: 80049217",
    "innerError": {
      "date": "2020-09-23T22:13:54",
      "request-id": "61be66ec-05e4-408f-9aa5-dec61829cea6",
      "client-request-id": "d73219c9-d26e-4972-9598-2a0ca6b6b8df"
    }
  }
}


    at com.microsoft.graph.http.GraphServiceException.createFromConnection(GraphServiceException.java:501)
    at com.microsoft.graph.http.CoreHttpProvider.handleErrorResponse(CoreHttpProvider.java:490)
    at com.microsoft.graph.http.CoreHttpProvider.sendRequestInternal(CoreHttpProvider.java:410)
    at com.microsoft.graph.http.CoreHttpProvider.send(CoreHttpProvider.java:207)
    at com.microsoft.graph.http.CoreHttpProvider.send(CoreHttpProvider.java:187)
    at com.microsoft.graph.http.BaseRequest.send(BaseRequest.java:345)
    at com.microsoft.graph.requests.extensions.DriveItemRequest.get(DriveItemRequest.java:84)
    at com.orion.FileAccess.graph.GraphConnectionTest.authError(GraphConnectionTest.java:73)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:50)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:26)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:325)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:78)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:57)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:26)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
    at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:137)
    at com.intellij.junit4.JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.java:69)
    at com.intellij.rt.junit.IdeaTestRunner$Repeater.startRunnerWithArgs(IdeaTestRunner.java:33)
    at com.intellij.rt.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:220)
    at com.intellij.rt.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:53)


Process finished with exit code 255
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This turned out to be a missing dependency, responsible for decoding the JSON responses. The `NoClassDefFound` error wasn't getting propagated. The underlying error was that no scopes were specified, which came through once I added the org.json JAR to my classpath. I used the scope `https://graph.microsoft.com/.default`.